# how to add if statement while verifying string with Regular Expressions in C

Tags: c, regex

I need to verify a String(string:`89dree01`) with regular expression (`[a-zA-Z0-9]*`) using if condition in C like so:
`if(string=regex) {}`

Could someone help me with this?

Below is the code snippet:

```c
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
     
int main()
{
    regex_t * regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]*";
         
    int value;
         
    value = regcomp(regex,"89dree01", 0);
         
    if (value == 0) {
        LOG("RegEx compiled successfully.");
    }
    else {
        LOG("Compilation error.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to choose a Regular Expression library for C and look at its documentation. I don't think Regular Expressions are part of C standard library.

Comment: Hi.  To help you we need more information, what library are you using, what is your exact desired output?

Comment: At least make an attempt.

Comment: Google _c regex library_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the POSIX regexp library quite correctly.

Here's an example that checks whether arguments given on the command line match that regexp (slightly modified).

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  regex_t regex;
  if (regcomp(&regex, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED)) {
    return 1;
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    int status = regexec(&regex, argv[i], 0, NULL, 0);
    printf("%s: %s\n", argv[i], status == REG_NOMATCH ? "no match" : "matched");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
~/Desktop $ gcc -o s s.c
~/Desktop $ ./s aaa bb0 00a11 ..--
aaa: matched
bb0: matched
00a11: matched
..--: no match
```

---

Edit:

Simply (if inefficiently) put, you can wrap this in a function:

```
int does_regexp_match(const char *string, const char *regexp) {
  regex_t r;
  if (regcomp(&r, regexp, REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED)) {
    return -1;
  }
  return regexec(&r, string, 0, NULL, 0) == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

```
if(does_regexp_match("89dree01", "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$") == 1) {
  // it's a match
}
```

Comment: @sreeja It's a pretty simple modification, but see my edit nonetheless.